# tf.nn.sigmoid implementation in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Could you please point me to the actual c++ implementation of the `tf.nn.sigmoid` function in TensorFlow (2.0) ? Just for educational purposes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tensorflow source can be little tricky to navigate.  Here's some ideas I use to find implementation files.

You can see that `tf.nn.sigmoid` is defined in python here

[tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py#L3134).

If you look at this function definition, you can see it returns a sigmoid function defined in `gen_math_ops`.  It took me awhile to figure out, but if you go searching for `gen_math_ops` in `tensorflow/python/ops` you won't find it.  Anything with `gen_` in front is the name tensorflow gives an op registered by C++ code.

What we really want in the kernel implementation.  These can be found in `tensorflow/core/kernels`.  A quick ctrl+f for `"sigmoid"` points us to `cwise_op_sigmoid.cc`.  This doesn't contain the implementation but points us to a header file `cwise_ops_common.h`.  This doesn't contain the implementation either, but points us to `cwise_ops.h`.  A ctrl+f for `"sigmoid"` in this file and we find the "implementation" on line [877](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_ops.h#L877).  You can see this is a functor that wraps the Eigen operation `Eigen::internal::scalar_logistic_op`.  [Here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/namespaceEigen.html#title43) are the docs for that op.  If you're curious how that op is implemented, I'd download the source.  You can find it [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).

Comment: For completeness, is this it? https://github.com/eigenteam/eigen-git-mirror/blob/b2ee7948a59c6cd5a2843786543f67b74a9928b7/Eigen/src/Core/functors/UnaryFunctors.h#L894

Comment: Thanks so much for digging this up, I needed it for a presentation.
Link to the tensorflow code mentioned:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/30a3ac9cf325108b6c8ac92fd05f588326fbf2fc/tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_ops.h#L923
And the gradients:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/30a3ac9cf325108b6c8ac92fd05f588326fbf2fc/tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_ops_gradients.h#L51